# Am I using PyPy wrong? It's slower 10x than standard Python

Tags: python, pypy

I have heard good stuff about PyPy. In particular I'd heard that it was very fast which made me wonder if it might be usable for an embedded project I have.

I downloaded `PyPy-2.6` for my `Windows 7` PC, and unzipped the contents into a directory.

I've written a small test program to allow me to benchmark:

```
import time

def fib(n):
        if n == 0 or n == 1:
                return 1
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

t0 = time.time()
fib(20)
t1 = time.time()

print t1-t0
```

So I went to the directory where PyPy was unzipped, ran `./pypy.exe hello.py` and got an answer of `0.120`.

Then I fired up a cygwin console and ran `python hello.py` and got an answer of `0.01`.

Am I using PyPy wrong or is it only faster for certain applications?

**Edit**

Thanks to Rob who pointed out that the JIT compiler needs time to warm up.

Extending my sample code produces the following results:

```
n     PyPy    Python
20    0.12     0.01
25    0.15     0.06
30    0.34     0.67
35    0.92     7.39
40    10.98    82.9
```

It seems like there's a 0.1 second start-up cost or something, but after that it's faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only faster for certain applications. Quoting the [PyPy doc](http://pypy.org/features.html):

> There are two cases that you should be aware where PyPy will not be able to speed up your code:
>
> - Short-running processes: if it doesn't run for at least a few seconds, then the JIT compiler won't have enough time to warm up.
> - If all the time is spent in run-time libraries (i.e. in C functions), and not actually running Python code, the JIT compiler will not help.

Since your program seems to run on the order of 10<sup><sup>-</sup>2</sup> or 10<sup><sup>-</sup>1</sup> seconds, the JIT compiler doesn't do you any good.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate with some more complex code with longer run time. It seems odd that it would actually slow my code down because it's short though.